# Dosage control through flow meter and valve

Tags: actuator, flow-control, solenoid-valve

I am trying to make a drinks machine that when a button is pressed, a predetermined amount of liquid (not determined by time) is allowed through a solenoid or other valve, and measured by a flow meter. Ideally the flow meter could be digitally linked but not essential.

I have been trawling the internet for days but I can't seem to find anything that determines by quantity of liquid, and not time dispensed. I would be enormously grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: If you know the flow rate of the liquid, then knowing the time the disperser has been running you also know the quantity dispensed. What's the problem exactly? Is there some reason you can't know the flow rate?

Comment: I had done a little thought experiment on something like this in my college days. The simplest way we thought of was actually having a "shot chamber", almost like an airlock. One valve opens and fills the chamber, then it closes, then the output valve opens and dispenses with gravity. This lets you not have to worry about pressure/viscosity/etc. Just have a 1 or 2 second timer, you'll get 99% of the liquids you use (unless you have a maple syrup shot, perhaps).

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply weight the glass with the drink while mixing it. The change of weight while pouring in an ingredient should be sufficient to determine the amount filled in.

Answer (score 2):

The application being described corresponds to a **dosing pump**, such as used in pharmaceutical and other chemical industries, and of course in pubs and bars.

The dosing pump is volumetric in operation, in order to ensure precision in liquid delivery volume despite (reasonable) differences in viscosity, inclination or in differential pressure between holding reservoir and receiver. Those are the key factors that cause flow rate to differ for the simpler time-based fluid metering pumps that the question refers to.

For high-viscosity fluids, such dosing pumps also have a drawback action at completion of metered fluid delivery, to prevent dosage variations due to dripping.

For instance, [this](http://www.ivek.com/digispense10.cont.mod.html) is an example of a long-lasting, precision dosing pump.

[image: Dosing pump]

For added precision, dual-chamber dosing pumps operate in a two-step way: The first impeller fills a precisely dimensioned reserve chamber, from which the second impeller forces the fluid out to the receiver. An enhancement sometimes used for hazardous fluids is to automatically prevent the second impeller from engaging unless the reserve chamber is full.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use a turbine or paddle-wheel type flowmeter. Some relatively inexpensive models are made by GEMS sensors such as their model [FT-330](http://www.gemssensors.com/Products/Flow/Electronic-Flow-Sensors/Turbo-Flow/FT-330-Series-Flow-Sensor). It has a pulse (Hall effect) output. You will need to integrate (simply count the pulses) to measure the total amount of liquid to determine your shut-off point. This particular product is designed for your type of application.

Since it is for human consumption, NSF (National Sanitary Foundation) approved materials and products should be used. Be sure to also consider how the sensor will be cleaned. Here's a link to the datasheet: [FT-330 Datasheet](http://www.gemssensors.com/Products/Flow/Electronic-Flow-Sensors/Turbo-Flow/~/media/GemsNA/NEW%20CATALOG%20FILES%20-%202013/FT-330.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to re-purpose a "tipping bucket rain gauge" sensor to measure the amount of liquid?  The actual mechanism within an off-the-shelf rain gauge sensor is actually quite small.